# JSON printing all paths from root to leaf

Tags: python, json

```
[
        {
            "name": "Basic",
            "id": "home",
            "childrens": [
                {
                    "name": "Dashboard",
                    "viewtype": "custom",
                    "view": "dashboard.html",
                    "childrens": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "DeviceInfo",
                    "href": "WSettings",
                    "childrens": [
                        {
                            "name": "DeviceInfo Form",
                            "childrens": [
                                {
                                    "name": "DeviceInfo Form1",
                                    "viewtype": "xml",
                                    "view": "dinfo",
                                    "childrens": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "DeviceInfo Form2",
                                    "viewtype": "xml",
                                    "view": "complexjson",
                                    "childrens": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "DeviceInfo Table",
                            "childrens": [
                                {
                                    "name": "DeviceInfo Table1",
                                    "viewtype": "xml",
                                    "view": "dinfotable",
                                    "childrens": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "DeviceInfo Table2",
                                    "viewtype": "xml",
                                    "view": "jsontable",
                                    "childrens": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }

                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Hybrid",
                    "childrens": [
                        {
                            "name": "Table-Form",
                            "viewtype": "xml",
                            "view": "hybrid",
                            "childrens": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Advanced",
            "id": "profile",
            "childrens": []
        }
]
```

Want to print all paths from root to leaf(one with empty **'childrens'**). **E.g Basic.DeviceInfo.DeviceInfo Form.DeviceInfo Form1**

Everything is going fine till **DeviceInfo Form2**

When it comes to **DeviceInfo Table**, **DeviceInfo Form** is coming into picture --> **Basic.DeviceInfo.DeviceInfo Form.DeviceInfo Table.DeviceInfo Table1.**

This should not happen. Instead I need **Basic.DeviceInfo.DeviceInfo Table.DeviceInfo Table1.**

Where am I going wrong with my code. Any solution?

```
def walk(list1, path = ""):
        for dic in list1:
            #print('about to walk', dic['name'], 'passing path -->', path)
            if(len(dic['childrens']) == 0):
                print('leaf --->', path+dic['name']+'.')
            else:
                path = path+dic['name']+'.'
                #passing parent name to childreni
                walk(dic['childrens'], path)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting your `path = path +dic['name']+'.'` in your else clause. Once the `walk()` function has finished traversing through the DeviceInfoForm 'childrens', it attempts to traverse the DeviceInfoTable. However, your function has already set path to 
`Basic.DeviceInfo.DeviceInfoForm.`

You need to reorganize your function so that the path isn't set in the `else:` statement. Perhaps

```
else:
    walk(dic['childrens'], path+dic['name']+'.')
```

That way you are passing the correct path to the function, but not explicitly setting it.