# To print all the paths in a json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gulp, jsonpath

What is the easy way to get all paths in the Given Json Object;
For Example:

```
{  
   app:{  
      profiles:'default'
   },
   application:{  
      name:'Master Service',
      id:'server-master'
   },
   server:{  
      protocol:'http',
      host:'localhost',
      port:8098,
      context:null
   }
}
```

I should able to produce the following object

```
app.profiles=default
application.name=Master Service
application.id=server-master
```

I was able to achieve the same using a recursive function. I want to know is there any built in function from json which does this.

Comment: would you please share your recursive function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement your custom converter by iterating through objects recursively.

Something like this:

```js
var YsakON = { // YsakObjectNotation
  stringify: function(o, prefix) {          
    prefix = prefix || 'root';
    
    switch (typeof o)
    {
      case 'object':
        if (Array.isArray(o))
          return prefix + '=' + JSON.stringify(o) + '\n';
        
        var output = ""; 
        for (var k in o)
        {
          if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) 
            output += this.stringify(o[k], prefix + '.' + k);
        }
        return output;
      case 'function':
        return "";
      default:
        return prefix + '=' + o + '\n';
    }   
  }
};

var o = {
 a: 1,
  b: true,
  c: {
    d: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  calc: 1+2+3,
  f: function(x) { // ignored
    
  }
};

document.body.innerText = YsakON.stringify(o, 'o');
```

That's not a best converter implementation, just a fast-written example, but it should help you to understand the main principle.

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/nbatLn6p/).

Comment: Thanks, I was checking is there any inbuilt function fron json, to print its all available paths, since json finally a tree structure.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no built-in function that does this. It can be done with a simple for loop as below in my fiddle. But it does not take care of recursiveness. Here are other posts that i found regarding the same : [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327815/print-all-paths-from-root-node-to-leaf-nodes-javascript) and [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571858/json-printing-all-paths-from-root-to-leaf) and [Post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183948/output-list-of-all-paths-to-leaf-nodes-in-a-json-document-in-java)

```
var myjson = {  
   app:{  
      profiles:'default'
   },
   application:{  
      name:'Master Service',
      id:'server-master'
   },
   server:{  
      protocol:'http',
      host:'localhost',
      port:8098,
      context:null
   }
};

for(key in myjson) {  
  for(k in myjson[key]) {
    console.log(key + '.' + k + ' = '+ myjson[key][k]);
  }  
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwv8fucf/1/)

Comment: This wont solve the purpose, because its only considering only one level, it has to be recursive as given by Yeldar Kurmangaliyev

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj1 = {
    "name" : "jane",
    "job" : {
        "first" : "nurse",
        "second" : "bartender",
        "last" : {
            "location" : "Paris",
            "work" : ["sleep", "eat", "fish", {"math" : "morning", "chem" : "late night"}],
            "read_books": {
                "duration" : 10,
                "books_read" : [{"title" : "Gone with the wind", "author": "I don't know"}, {"title": "Twologht", "author": "Some guy"}]
            }
        }
    },
    "pets": ["cow", "horse", "mr. peanutbutter"],
    "bf" : ["jake", "beatles", {"johnson": ["big johnson", "lil johnson"]}]    
}

var obj2 = ["jane", "jake", {"age" : 900, "location": "north pole", "name" : "Jim", "pets" : "..."}];

var allRoutes = [];

function findTree(o, parentKey = '', parentObject)
{
    if (typeof o !== 'object')
    {
        if (parentKey.substr(0,1) === '.')
            allRoutes.push(parentKey.substr(1));
        else
        allRoutes.push(parentKey);

        return;
    }

    let keys = Object.keys(o);

    for (let k in keys)
    {
        findTree(o[keys[k]], Array.isArray(o) ? parentKey + "[" +keys[k] + "]" :  parentKey + "." +keys[k], o);     
        //findTree(o[keys[k]], parentKey + "[" +keys[k] + "]");     
    }
}

findTree(obj1);
```

Try this.